# Jboss license with jBPM

Tags: jbpm

Hi planning to use jBPM for my project in an enterprise the latest jBMP 7.36.0 Final comes with JBoss. I have read before that jBoss is affiliated to RedHat licensing which has paid subscription for enterprise usage. Although jBPM is Apache licence which permits usage without a subscription. So if I use jBPM with JBoss will there be a problem, if yes is there a guide to host jBPM on tomcat? Is this hosting on tomcat possible? Please help me out if anyone has encountered similar kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JBoss is paid and without having subscription you can't use it.
But you have a choice to use [Wildfly](https://wildfly.org/) which is upstream of JBoss EAP and it is community version and free.

Here is the link [for installation of jBPM on tomcat](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.33.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_tomcat_7_x8_x).